Hercules predicted the Moors would conquer Spain?
I have read that in Spanish legend, King Roderic/Rodrigo, last King of the Visigoths before the invasion of the Moors, insisted on entering the cave or tower of Hercules, left sealed since the times of Greek myth but forced open by Roderic, thinking there would be treasure inside. Instead, he found a statue of Hercules and a depiction of Moors labelled to the effect that when seen, men such as them would conquer Spain. I have also read that there are versions of the legend on the Islamic side as well, but haven't found the original or translation of any. The book "Moorish Spain" by Richard A. Fletcher cites "Ahmad Ar-Razi" as the eldest source, (presumably Ahmad ibn Muhammad ibn Musa al-Razi, who wikipedia calls a Muslim historian of Persian origin born in Córdoba Al-Andalus), the anonymous "Ajbar Machmua", "Ibn Adhari" and "al-Maqqari"
In the 13th century, Rodrigo Jiménez de Rada mentions Hercules but doesn't claim he built the tower/cave, only that the Moorish invasion was as bad as that of Hercules. The same is true in Alfonso X.
The 15th century Crónica Del Rey Don Rodrigo mentions Hercules as the builder of the tower in Toledo and Rodrigo's opening of it.
In the 16th century, Juan de Mariana's History of Spain mentions Hercules, and Roderic opening a castle and finding the prophecy of his defeat by the Moors, but makes no claim that Hercules built the castle.
Is Crónica Del Rey Don Rodrigo the oldest source linking Hercules to the tower/cave Roderic/Rodrigo entered?

The book "Moorish Spain" by Richard A. Fletcher says the legend is recorded in both Christian and Muslim sources, citing "Ahmad Ar-Razi" as the eldest source, (presumably Ahmad ibn Muhammad ibn Musa al-Razi, who wikipedia calls a Muslim historian of Persian origin born in Córdoba Al-Andalus), the anonymous "Ajbar Machmua", "Ibn Adhari" and "al-Maqqari"

It seems that documents are citing Crónicas del moro Rasis, however in Spanish the manuscripts available are incomplete, the three available ones skip the history of Rodrigo.

Try also Crónica de 1344, I have not found a good transcript...

The story of Roderic (not named) is mentioned in One thousand and one nights under "The city of Lebtait" (no mention of Hercules either). Could this story be the source? Or was this story inspired by Crónica del Rey Don Rodrigo?

It would depend on whether the story is in the original manuscripts for 1001 Nights or one of the later stories Antoine Galland added in his translation, like Aladdin and Alibaba and the 40 thieves
